# Problemas em JBoss 6 - lentidão para leitura de arquivos e filas JMS

Tags: jboss

boa tarde

Gostaria da ajuda de vocês para tentar resolver este problema que estou enfrentando a alguns dias em um JBoss 6 que tenho hospedado em um VPS. Ocorre que venho observando o seguinte warning a todo instante nos logs do JBoss: "ARJUNA-16037 Could not find new XAResource to use for recovering non-serializable XAResource". Além disso percebi uma lentidão absurda para a leitura de arquivos via código java (a leitura de um simples arquivo xml está levando mais de 20 segundos) e também no tempo que mensagens JMS levam para serem processadas (existem mensagens JMS presas com aproximadamente 2 dias de delay). Alguém saberia me dar ao menos uma pista para resolver estes problemas ? Obs: Eu já reiniciei o JBoss, já parei e subi novamente o MySql da máquina (sendo que eu não tenho utilizado operações em banco atualmente) e também já reiniciei o apache.

Muito Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Alguém teria alguma dica, pessoal ?

Answer (score 1):

o problema na lentidão de leitura era porque o arquivo em questão tinha mais registros do que eu pensava,  neste caso adotei uma solução com base em BD e o problema foi resolvido. Com relação ao warning "ARJUNA-16037 Could not find new XAResource to use for recovering non-serializable XAResource", o mesmo foi resolvido apagando uma pasta no JBoss, se não me engano estava em "server/default/data"... Também alterei as configurações do HornetQ (JMS) para ter menos consumidores de filas, assim diminuindo o uso de memória.